"Add app to show function keys in Touch Bar instead of App Controls" ignores the added Apps?
I have added PyCharm to the list of Apps for which the function keys should respond to App configured behaviors instead of macOS level configurations. E.g. F3 should "Find next" in the current editor screen.

However F3 is doing the MacOS thing instead of showing the Desktop. So then how can Pycharm be configured to properly use the Function keys - without resorting to the Use F1,F2,etc keys as standard function keys (which imposes that behavior system-wide) ?
I am on Sonoma 14.5.
